# Transferring data from Sql server to SQLITE with Android

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite

I have software that connects to an SQL database. I am now working on the software on Android, using SQLite, and need to transfer the SQL database (with the data) to SQLite.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create the SQLite database on the device and download and persist the data into the local SQLite data base. A good place to read up on how to do this is [in the Android docs.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Another possible solution would be to create the SQLite database at the server level and download it directly within the Android app then open it. But if you modify anything locally within the app you would need to send data back to the server to keep in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Create Rest API that will fetch my SQL data in JSON format.
Now from android app access that API to get data and insert that data in in your SQLite.
or if you want to fetch it in background process use sync Adapter.